# Can't retrieve images using Universal Image Loader in Android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am very new to `Universal Image Loader` library. I am trying to load images into a listview. This is the tutorial I have referred `http://cbpbenitez.blogspot.in/2013/11/universal-image-loader-tutorial.html`. The problem is that no image is getting displayed. I have no errors in my project. I am posting the full code here, please guide me step by step.

MainActivity.class

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

ImageListAdapter.class

```
  public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] urls = {
        "http://tabletpcssource.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/android-logo.png",
        "http://simpozia.com/pages/images/stories/windows-icon.png",
        "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1135218951/gmail_profile_icon3_normal.png",
        "http://www.krify.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Macromedia_Flash_dock_icon.png",
        "http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/radio.png",
        "http://www.bandwidthblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/twitter-logo.png",
        "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100907_itunes1.png",
        "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100929_applications.png",
        "http://www.idyllicmusic.com/index_files/get_apple-iphone.png",
        "http://www.frenchrevolutionfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/Twitter-Bird.png",
        "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ka5MiRGJ_S4/TdD9OoF6bmI/AAAAAAAAE8k/7ydKtptUtSg/s1600/Google_Sky%2BMaps_Android.png",
        "http://www.desiredsoft.com/images/icon_webhosting.png",
        "http://goodereader.com/apps/wp-content/uploads/downloads/thumbnails/2012/01/hi-256-0-99dda8c730196ab93c67f0659d5b8489abdeb977.png",
        "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mlaJ4p_3rBU/TdD9OWxN8II/AAAAAAAAE8U/xyynWwr3_4Q/s1600/antivitus_free.png",
        "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transformers/computer.png",
        "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/firefox.png?7794fe",
        "https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.rovio.angrybirdsseasons/hi-256-9-347dae230614238a639d21508ae492302340b2ba",
        "http://androidblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/tablet-pc-256x256.jpg",
        "http://www.theblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Apple.png",
        "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y-HQwQ4Kuu0/TdD9_iKIY7I/AAAAAAAAE88/3G4xiclDZD0/s1600/Twitter_Android.png",
        "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nAf4IMJGpc8/TdD9OGNUHHI/AAAAAAAAE8E/VM9yU_lIgZ4/s1600/Adobe%2BReader_Android.png",
        "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/oovoo-android.png?7794fe",
        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kocco/ndroid/128/android-market-2-icon.png",
        "http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png",
        "http://c.wrzuta.pl/wm16596/a32f1a47002ab3a949afeb4f",
        "http://macprovid.vo.llnwd.net/o43/hub/media/1090/6882/01_headline_Muse.jpg"
};

private Context context;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = convertView;

    ViewHolder vh = null;
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_item, null);

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        v.setTag(vh);
    }
    else {
        vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .build();

    imageLoader.displayImage(urls[position], vh.imageView, options);

    return v;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}

 }
```

UILDemoApplication.class

```
    public class UILDemoApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
    .enableLogging() 
    .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}

 }
```

Permissions

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: where you are setting ImageListAdapter to your listview or gridview ?

Comment: Thanks ...I din set the adapter. its working now

Comment: Have you checked network state using NetworkInfo? The log is generated with the tag of ImageLoader, what does this log says about the images, and the responses? You can initialize the options, and call init, just once in the onCreate() of the activity. You initialize your options: options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true).build();

Answer (score 1):

Before using `imageloader.displayimage` mathod you have to intialize imageloader first.

to initialize image loader try this method

```
private void configImageLoader() {

        // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this
        // configuration
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(
                getDisplayImageOptions()) // default
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
```

try this

```
    public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] urls = {
            "http://tabletpcssource.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/android-logo.png",
            "http://simpozia.com/pages/images/stories/windows-icon.png",
            "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1135218951/gmail_profile_icon3_normal.png",
            "http://www.krify.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Macromedia_Flash_dock_icon.png",
            "http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/radio.png",
            "http://www.bandwidthblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/twitter-logo.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100907_itunes1.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100929_applications.png",
            "http://www.idyllicmusic.com/index_files/get_apple-iphone.png",
            "http://www.frenchrevolutionfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/Twitter-Bird.png",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ka5MiRGJ_S4/TdD9OoF6bmI/AAAAAAAAE8k/7ydKtptUtSg/s1600/Google_Sky%2BMaps_Android.png",
            "http://www.desiredsoft.com/images/icon_webhosting.png",
            "http://goodereader.com/apps/wp-content/uploads/downloads/thumbnails/2012/01/hi-256-0-99dda8c730196ab93c67f0659d5b8489abdeb977.png",
            "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mlaJ4p_3rBU/TdD9OWxN8II/AAAAAAAAE8U/xyynWwr3_4Q/s1600/antivitus_free.png",
            "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transformers/computer.png",
            "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/firefox.png?7794fe",
            "https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.rovio.angrybirdsseasons/hi-256-9-347dae230614238a639d21508ae492302340b2ba",
            "http://androidblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/tablet-pc-256x256.jpg",
            "http://www.theblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Apple.png",
            "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y-HQwQ4Kuu0/TdD9_iKIY7I/AAAAAAAAE88/3G4xiclDZD0/s1600/Twitter_Android.png",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nAf4IMJGpc8/TdD9OGNUHHI/AAAAAAAAE8E/VM9yU_lIgZ4/s1600/Adobe%2BReader_Android.png",
            "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/oovoo-android.png?7794fe",
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kocco/ndroid/128/android-market-2-icon.png",
            "http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png",
            "http://c.wrzuta.pl/wm16596/a32f1a47002ab3a949afeb4f",
            "http://macprovid.vo.llnwd.net/o43/hub/media/1090/6882/01_headline_Muse.jpg"
    };

    private Context context;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        configImageLoader();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = convertView;

        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_item, null);

            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            v.setTag(vh);
        }
        else {
            vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(urls[position], vh.imageView, options);

        return v;
    }

 private void configImageLoader() {

            // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this
            // configuration
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(
                    getDisplayImageOptions()) // default
                    .build();

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

     }
```

Comment: What is getDisplayImageOptions() functions? When I write it it gives me an eror in the editor saying create a method getDisplayImageOptions(). please help.

Comment: now try it `public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayImageOptions() {
  DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory().build();

  return displayOptions;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You have created a instance of ImageLoader but have not Initialize ImageLoader. For this add this line of code in your constructor after imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); :

   imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ctx));
2. You have not declared any option for your imageLoader. Modify your DisplayImageOptions code as below:

   DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
           .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.image_loading)
           .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image)
           .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.image_failed)
           .cacheInMemory(true)
           .cacheOnDisc(true)
           .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
           .build();